# Get user's Event log google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I manage one big social mobile app. We integrated google mobile Analytics in android and iphone app both. Also added custom variables like userid.

We want to analyse new user activity after 20 min of signup. I want to get email after 20 min of new signup and i would like to get user activity so that i can analyse what user did in initial 20 min. We put google analytics event in each action and i can see over all analytics in google analytics panel.

But I am interested in user level activity like :

Adam's activity :

02/01/2015 12:15 PM : Did signup through email

02/01/2015 12:15 PM : Invited x friend

02/01/2015 12:15 PM : Added x friend

02/01/2015 12:15 PM : Enabled location server

etc

Currently I track all these events but I couldn't find any google analytics api to get these activity back through api.

Is there any api available to get user wise event log ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that userid is being tracked in Custom Variable 1, it is possible to get the data you mentioned in the question with the following query -

Dimensions - customVarValue01,date,hour,minute,eventCategory,eventAction

Metrics - uniqueEvents

You would also have to add a Filters parameter to filter on the desired Events. Try diving into the [Core Reporting API documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) and [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries)

Comment: Thanks. I think this reply will help us. We are trying to implement that.

Comment: This can be used to query online: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/